# Additional arguments for custom deleter of shared_ptr

Tags: c++, smart-pointers

Is there anyway I can send arguments to the deleter of `std::shared_ptr`?

something that would feel like:

```
std::shared_ptr<A> myA( a, myDeleter(a, 5) );
```

where `myDeleter` has this signature:

```
void myDeleter(A* a, int i)
```

(Obviously the syntax above is wrong, but just to emphasize that I need my deleter to take extra arguments.)

Answer (score 26, accepted):

You could `std::bind` your deleter's second argument before passing it as the deleter:

```
auto deleter = std::bind(myDeleter, std::placeholders::_1, 5);
std::shared_ptr<A> myA(a, deleter);
```

Alternatively, your deleter could be a functor that takes the `int` through its constructor:

```
struct myDeleter
{
  myDeleter(int);
  void operator()(A*);
};

myDeleter deleter(5);
std::shared_ptr<A> myA(a, deleter);
```

Alternatively you could use a lambda expression:

```
std::shared_ptr<A> myA(a, [](A* a){ myDeleter(a, 5); });
```

Comment: brill. many thanks! why were lambdas only introduced so recently in C++?!